# Symfony 2 Doctrine find by ordered array of id

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I'm looking for a way to use `Doctrine` in `Symfony 2` to find items using an ordered array of id.

I have a Card entity with id (primary key) and title.

I have a ListCards entity with id (primary key) and a listCards (an array of ids encoded : `["16", "2", "84"]`)

I first fetch the list and then I need to find cards with those ids in that order.

I try something like :

```
$idsArray = ["16", "2", "84"];
$cardRepository->findby($idsArray);
```

**but** `Doctrine` fetch my cards in `ASC` order.

`ORDER BY FIEDS` sql method doesn't seem to be supported by doctrine.

Is there any simple solution for that kind of sorting ?

Thank you (and sorry for my bad english).

Answer (score 36):

You can use it like:

```
$cardRepository->findBy( array('id' => $idsArray), array('id' => 'DESC') );
```

Check also [the official doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions) for more details on how to use ordering, limit and offset as second to fourth parameters in the `findBy` method.

Comment: Thank for your answer but i don't want a DESC order but my array order. And I don't find any parameters in ‘findBy‘ method that allow this kind of feature.

Comment: You can send array $idsArray and array with entities to twig. Then you can use loop for $idsArray.

Comment: I was not able to do this directly in Doctrine, but here's a way to get a specified ordering (4, 7, 1, 6 in this example) from Postgres:

```select *
from my_table
join unnest('{4,7,1,6}'::varchar[]) with ordinality o(my_id, ord) on o.my_id = my_table.my_id
order by ord asc;```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper table, where you store ordered group elements, having the following data: `(group_id, card_id, order)`

You search by `group`_id, order by `order` and read the `card_id`.

Comment: Thank you. I will try something like this. Too bad there is no sort parameter other than ASC ou DESC in findBy doctrine method.